# GUI automation using SendMessage

Tags: winapi, user-interface, automation

I have developed a GUI automation tool which simulates user clicks on UI controls. All seems to work fine on local machinein. But problem starts if I run it having via remote desktop. The focus seems to be going out of context and none of the controls get clicked. The tool uses PostMessage/SendMessage to send messages to UI. Any suggestions how this could be tackled? And what are the possible causes for this kind of behavior pertaining to remote desktop.

Comment: Why not use UI automation?

Comment: It's already a working solution. Changing it to something new would be lots of effort and time.

Comment: It seems to me that your solution is not working

Comment: it works on local machine

Comment: The answer to just about any question along the lines of "HELP! Can't seem to `SendMessage` messages to another process" is [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). As David summed it up nicely already: Your solution does not work. If you absolutely must fake mouse/keyboard input, at least use the correct tool: [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx). It solves many (but not all) issues that you will eventually experience using `SendMessage` or `PostMessage`.

Comment: it works on local machine but not when logged from remote desktop.

Comment: As I said, it seems that your solution is not working

Comment: David I tried UI Automation, to be frank it sucks. Most of the controls in that GUI doesn't even show up in UI spy, without Automation ID im sure UI Automation is good for clicking buttons on calculators. Seems to be not a solution for this problem.

Comment: Managed to make my solution work!!! It was a handle problem. Thanks anyways even though nothing useful was given as a suggestion.